# 5F, page 51, van Lint-Wilson.

Tags: combinatorics

Question : Let $A_1, A_2,...,A_n$ be finite sets. Show that if
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{|A_i\cap A_j|}{|A_i|\cdot|A_j|}<1$$
then the sets $A_1, A_2,...A_n$ have a system of distinct representatives.

My attempt: To do so, we will use induction on $|S|$ to prove that $\{A_i\mid i\in S\subseteq[n]\}$ satisfy Hall's condition. If $|S|=1$, then clearly the inequality holds. Now suppose the inequality holds for all subsets $T$ with $|T|\leq k-1$, and consider a set $S$ with $|S|=k$. We need to prove that
$$ \left|\bigcup_{i\in S}A_i\right|\geq |S|=k$$
Now we have
\begin{align*}
 \left|\bigcup_{j\in S}A_j\right| &= |A_i| + \left|\bigcup_{j\neq i}A_j\right| -  \left|A_i\bigcap\left(\bigcup_{j\in T}A_j\right)\right|
\end{align*}
We need to chose an $A_i$ such that $RHS\geq k$, but it is trivial that $RHS\geq k-1$ because $|\cup_{j\neq i}A_j|\geq k-1$ by induction and $|A_i|\geq |A_i\cap(\cup_{j\neq i}A_j)|$.

If such $A_i$ doesn't exist, which means that $$\left|\bigcup_{j\neq i}A_j\right|= k-1 \quad \text{and}\quad \big|A_i\big|= \left|A_i\bigcap\big(\bigcup_{j\in T}A_j\big)\right|$$ for $\forall i\in S$.

Now we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\bigg|A_i\bigcap\big(\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j\big)\bigg|}{|A_i||\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}
=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{|\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}
=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{k-1}
=\frac{k}{k-1}>1$$

But on the other hand

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\bigg|A_i\bigcap\big(\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j\big)\bigg|}{|A_i||\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}\big(A_i\bigcap A_j\big)}{|A_i||\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\sum\limits_{j\neq i}|A_j\cap A_i|}{|A_i||\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j\neq i}\frac{|A_j\cap A_i|}{|A_i||\bigcup\limits_{j\neq i}A_j|}
=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j\neq i}\frac{|A_j\cap A_i|}{|A_i|}\\
&=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\bigg(\frac{|A_j\cap A_i|}{|A_i|}+\frac{|A_j\cap A_i|}{|A_j|}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{|A_j\cap A_i|(|A_i|+|A_j|)}{|A_i||A_j|}
\end{align*}

Hence I want to prove that $|A_i|+|A_j|\leq k-1$.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: I find that $|A_i|+|A_j|\leq k$ is also useful.

Comment: Hint: Probabilistic method.

Comment: See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2337441p18810547)

Comment: Thank you very much.